# What was Banto watching in Dr Who 'Blink'?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Dr Who episode 'Blink' we see Sally Sparrow (just after leaving Kathy Nightingale's grave) enter Banto's DVD store, the sound of gunfire comes from a TV in the store

She approaches the counter to ask the owner for Larry Nightingale but he shushes her for a moment to continue watching a film, it shows a woman dressed in white dashing into a building, as soon as the on-screen woman is inside he then gives Sally his attention.

Is there anywhere in the script or whatever that states what Banto is watching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Tardis wikia page for that character](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Banto_(Blink)):

> When Sally Sparrow came in, Banto was watching an episode of the BBC series Gangsters, and complained about how characters on TV never go to the police. This gave Sally the idea to go to the police.